# Is there a limit on TextBlob translation?

Tags: python, google-translate, textblob

I have been using TextBlob, a package for Python (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/textblob) for translating articles to different language .

After reading their docs, I got to know that TextBlob makes use of Google Translate. Since google translate is not a free service, I wanted to know whether there is any usage limit on translating articles using TextBlob services?

Answer (score 8):

Google states on their pricing page for the Google Translate API that you need to set up billing in order to be able to utilize the translate API. In other words, there isn't a free usage tier.

> Important: Google Translate API v2 requires billing information for all accounts before you 
>   can start using the service.

This text is available on `https://cloud.google.com/translate/v2/pricing`.

So, you shouldn't be able to use the translate API at all unless you have an account set up.

The Google documentation lists `https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2` as the API endpoint. Having a look around the source code for TextBlob, I couldn't find that endpoint mentioned anywhere. Instead, TextBlob seems to be using [http://translate.google.com/translate_a/t](https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob/blob/fd245b8ebf7c4e30103495f14a30907dacb1bede/textblob/translate.py), and that URL isn't mentioned anywhere in Google's API documentation. It seems like TextBlob isn't using the Google Translate API at all. Instead, its forging headers and claiming to be a browser.

[This](https://github.com/terryyin/google-translate-python) is the module which TextBlob adapted its translation feature from, which states `No key, no authentication whatsoever` in its description.

So I guess there isn't any usage limit on translating articles using TextBlob, since its not using the API.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. At the time I'm writing this, it's 1000 words/day.

TextBlog internally uses Terry Yin's [google-translate-python](https://github.com/terryyin/google-translate-python) which now uses [MyMemory](http://mymemory.translated.net/) instead Google Translate.

According to [MyMemory: API usage limits](http://mymemory.translated.net/doc/usagelimits.php):

> Free, anonymous usage is limited to 1000 words/day.

Comment: I dont think the assessment is correct . I am using textblob-0.11.1.dist-info and call to detect_language() ( provided by textblob uses google api. During debugging I found follow url is used 

http://translate.google.com/translate_a/t

Answer (score 0):

Even this question old, I will post answer for future references. I have been using this TextBlob translation and found out that actual limit is about 500 per day.

I had to translate file with about 1100 requests so I had to use some VPN Providers to change my IP Address. I advice [Windscribe VPN provider](https://windscribe.com/)

hope it helps someone.